# How to print only sub-category name

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm trying to figure out how to print only sub-category of a given category. There is one parent category, called "Local". This parent category has six sub-categories, each of them is a city name. Each post is associated with the parent category, Local, and one of the sub-categories.
For example,

Post A - Local and City 1

Post B - Local and City 2

I want to print out only the sub-category name within the loop. I've come across the following code in wordpress forums but it doesn't help me as it prints out the parent category name as well.

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo ( $category->cat_name != 'local' ) ? $category->cat_name . ' ' : ''; } ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent category name is literally "Local" with the capital L, try changing the code to the following:

```
<?php 
 foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
  echo ( $category->cat_name != 'Local' ) ? $category->cat_name . ' ' : ''; 
 }
?>
```

Comment: No problem, I love fixing typos even more than making them ;)